# Magento 2: Paypal Oder Place Event

Tags: magento2

I have observer `checkout_submit_all_after` this event not working with PayPal payment method.

Answer (score 3):

The `checkout_submit_all_after` event will not worked with PayPal. You can use the `paypal_express_place_order_success` event for a PayPal order success.

> app/code/Vendor/Paypal/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="paypal_express_place_order_success">
        <observer name="vendor_place_order_paypal_express_observer" instance="Vendor\Paypal\Observer\PaypalSuccessAfter"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

***Hope it helps!!!***

Comment: i need create new observer ?

Comment: <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="webkul_purchasemanagement_sales_order_place_after" instance="Webkul\PurchaseManagement\Observer\AfterPlaceOrder" />
    </event>

Comment: Yes, you need to create a new observer for PayPal as I shared above the event file.

Answer (score 0):

> sales_order_place_after

This event is working for paypal express, amazon pay, Sagepay, COD etc.. (Magento 2.4.2)